# How to do SQL update and have one rwo per id?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table in the following format:

```
id  Value
1   1
2   0.5
2   0.5
3   0.7
3   0.3
4   0.2
4   0.8
5   0
5   1
```

I want to update this table so I can get it in the following format:

```
id  Value
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
```

Is there a way to update this without first updating all values to 1 and then removing the duplicate rows?

Comment: @woz yes if that is possible, basically each id's value needs to sum to 1

Comment: how then sum of id 4 be 1 when it has only one value 0.2, and same for id 5 it has zero only.  I think, either I am missing here or you are?

Comment: @Piyush thanks for pointing that out, I have made the edits in the question

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id,SUM(Value)
from myTable
group by id
order by id
```

Comment: you are missing from clause

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
update t
SET t.col = b.total
FROM t INNER JOIN 
(select id,SUM(col) as total from t
group by id
) as b
ON t.id = b.id
```

Remove duplicate after this

```
    delete from t 
    where id in(select id from t group by id having
    count(*) >1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1e9f/13